# Accepted answer checkmark color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, accepting

I just asked this question at [meta.programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/accepted-answer-checkmark-color) when I realized I have the same problem over here as well.

When I ask a question (and every answer has a check mark next to it for me to select one as my accepted answer), it's very hard for me to tell the difference between the check mark that I've checked, and one that I haven't checked.

Could you either use a darker green for the one that I've checked, or make the unchecked ones appear as an outline like on StackOverflow?

Comment: I see that you mark tagged this "accessibility".  May I ask, do you have some visual impairment?  (I apologise if the question is rude; my reason for asking is that if so, that would make me personally put this at a higher priority than otherwise.)

Comment: I'm red-green blind.

Comment: That's useful to know.  Thanks.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same question but thought "Let's see if anybody has posted this before ... not gonna be the case anyway". Well. So yes, I'm red-green deficient as well and it's terribly hard for me to tell whether I've clicked the check mark or not. If anybody wants to get an idea what it's like, I always show the [sample pictures](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot-Gr%C3%BCn-Sehschw%C3%A4che#Simulation_der_Rot-Gr.C3.BCn-Sehschw.C3.A4che_f.C3.BCr_Trichromaten) in the German Wikipedia article on red-green deficiency to my friends.

Comment: I've checked briefly meta.stackoverflow.com and couldn't find a question regarding colour blindness accessibility. If you are willing, you can also ask a more generic question there with your accessibility concerns to be taken into consideration when designing new sites. Should you decide to do so, please post a link back and we'd support your question with upvotes.

Comment: @Martin: I've posted this at meta.stackoverflow.com now. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92499/green-checkmark-on-new-se-sites

Comment: @Jin: Could you do something regarding this? It would be great. I find it hard to distinguish too, using an outline would be perfect.

Comment: I things likes this should be categorized as bugs, not feature requests.

Comment: I feel you Ken :) I am also colorblind and I had a few check/uncheck cases.

Comment: @percusse (and @Ken): Jin says that this will be fixed in the next deployment.  I don't know when that is, but if you notice the change could you report back and let us know if it is now okay?  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Sure, I have also heard the same complaint from the people who are healthy as an eagle but using a horrible laptop display angle.

Comment: @AndrewStacey It is already changed and much better (though I would have preferred an outlined checkmark, similar to the voting buttons).

Comment: @Caramdir It has changed but I can't agree that it is better. it really very much depends on the monitor you are viewing (for color blinds that is). The main difficulty is that there are no spatial cues to tell the differences if the color is not helping. And I can't understand the reason why not adding a simple difference is not implemented between the accepted and the others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry I missed this request. I have adjusted the contrast between the checkmark's on and off state significantly. This change will be in the next production build.

Comment: Thanks, Jin.  For future reference, what is the best way to bring such things to your attention?  It soon became clear that no-one on the team had noticed this, but then I (for one) wasn't sure how to flag it for your attention.  It'd be nice to know the correct incantation to summon the Jin!

Comment: @AndrewStacey We read our SE sites' Meta regularly, but sometimes bug reports do get missed. I made a tag-set on stackexchange.com that tracks "bug" and "design" related questions. But obviously it's not 100% reliable since I missed this post. The best way to reach me is simply @ Jin in a comment or chatroom, without having to create a new post on Meta. I'll get the notification in my global inbox. You can always email me at jin[@]stackexchange.com too.

Comment: @Jin: Until yesterday this was tagged with [tag:feature-request] instead of [tag:bug], so your tag-set couldn't have picked it up.

Comment: @Jin: thanks for that.  I think that the "design" tag seems most appropriate as the first method.

Comment: Much better. Thanks. And thanks to whoever retagged this as a bug, rather than a feature request.

Comment: I just noticed that meta.tex also needs the same fix.

Comment: @Ken you're right, I missed Meta. I'll make sure that go in tonight's build.

Answer (score 15):

I support this feature request.

Unfortunately, we (the site users and moderators) don't have any control over the CSS so we have to wait until this is brought to the attention of the SO overlords (and Jin, the site designer in particular, I guess).

Comment: +1 They might even support some alternative CSS style for the visual impaired. After all, 7-10% of all people are red-green blind (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Epidemiology)).