# Rename {accessability} to {accessibility} (on meta)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, meta

It's just a typo, "accessability" isn't a standard spelling, you can ask [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accessability?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic), [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=accessability), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accessability) or whomever. Google judges 170m : 805k in favor of "accessibility".

On a side note, I'd be interested in a solution to the [only question tagged with {accessi/ability}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/844/accepted-answer-checkmark-color) as well ...

Comment: done. (And to fill the remaining space: I'd also be interested in a solution.)

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks! Should I close this question? Do we need an accepted answer here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag's name is now [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility).